# Wordpress won't load in chrome but other browsers?

Tags: wordpress, cross-browser, google-chrome

I have a website where chrome doesn't even load at all on wordpress. Any ever had this happen to them?

site: egore.globerunnerseo.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have unbalanced tags here:

(div id="header-logo" class="hide") (a href="http://egore.globerunnerseo.com" title="Eric Gore")
    Eric Gore" /)(/a)

There's an extra ">" there. I replaced "<" and ">" with "(" and ")" to avoid writing HTML